# Are "until" and "before" close to interchangeable in this context?

Tags: word-choice, difference, idiomatic-language

> If you say it happened three hours ago, why haven't you contacted us
> until/before now.

- Does the sentence have the same meaning no matter which of "until" and "before" I choose?
- Is one of them more natural than the other in a context like this?

Comment: I think you need something like: "why haven't you contacted us earlier?"

Comment: _Until_ implies that the condition has now ended, whereas _before_ does not have that implication. Since they have evidently contacted them now (the condition has ended), there is no difference in meaning in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"...why haven't you contacted us *before* now" sounds more natural to my ear.

If you want to use "until," the following construction works better:

> If you say it happened three hours ago, why have you waited until now to contact us?

The word "before" (in the sense of "earlier than" or "sooner than") works as a modifier to the word "now", while "until" indicates a time span ending at a certain point, which when used with the *negative* construction "why haven't you" tends to be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase has been written slightly wrong. Try this

> If you say it happened three hours ago, why haven't you contacted us.. until now/before.

The two are now fully interchangeable.

---

Theoretically the meanings are slightly different but in this instance the use is exactly the same.